# Having issue while seclect the first child in jquery (need to optimize the code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I need to remove and add the class to certain IDs using jquery.I had done but the code was not optimized. Am having a problem while selecting the first child of each id. that's why too many lines in this code. can you please help me to optimize the code?

```js
if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22092 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22093 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22094 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22099 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22103 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22104 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22129 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22130 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22131 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22136 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22140 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22141 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22145 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22146 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22151 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22156 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22160 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22161 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22166 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22171 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22228 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22233 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22238 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22195 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22196 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22197 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22202 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22206 a").first().removeClass("megamenu-header-background");
   }
  else {
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22092 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22093 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22094 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22099 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22103 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22104 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22104 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22129 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22130 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22131 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22136 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22140 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22141 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22145 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22146 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22151 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22156 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22160 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22161 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22166 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22171 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22228 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22233 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22238 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22195 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22196 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22197 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22202 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
    jQuery("#mega-menu-item-22206 a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
  }
```

Can you please share the idea to optimize the code in a single line like below,

```js
    jQuery("#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_2,#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_3,#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_4,#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_5,#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_6,#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_7").addClass('megamenu-item-header-background');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `$("[id^=mega-menu-item] a").first()`

Answer (score 1):

you could make a for loop over all the elements which statisfies your id construction.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')

for (const i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].id.includes("mega-menu-item")) {
    jQuery("#" + elements[i].id + " a").first().addClass("megamenu-header-background");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why mix vanilla js and jquery? A simple jquery is to use `$("[id^=mega-menu-item] a")`

Comment: I don't like much jquery, is legacy code and has newest options to use in updated code.. I prefer vanilla JS when suggesting new solutions - but you are right too!

Comment: It's fine that you don't like jquery, but I don't understand why you mix it then?

Comment: just to keep consistency with the question